# How to keep decimal value when getting data from a text file?

Tags: c++, syntax, fstream

I have a text file with info like this (there are 127 lines, I'll provide a few too keep it short):

```
Gibraltar 133.25
Israel 104.81
Seychelles 85.89
United-Arab-Emirates 63.95
Falkland-Islands 49.73
```

My program does work in printing country name and number with the most vaccinations, however it just prints a whole number with no decimals. This is especially problematic with lowest since theres multiple countries with numbers between 0 and 1, and it just prints the first 0 down the list, so not the true minimum, here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void file(string country[], double vaccinations[]);
void highest(string country[], double vaccinations[]);
void lowest(string country[], double vaccinations[]);
void average (string country[], double vaccinations[]);
void welcomeMessage();

int main() {
    //declare variables and arrays, set vaccinations and countries arrays to 127 for the number of countries, amd subsequent vaccination data
    string countries[127];
    double vaccinations[127];
    file(countries, vaccinations);
      
    //call wecome message function
    welcomeMessage();
    //calls function to count highest vaccination rate and country names
    highest(countries, vaccinations);
    cout << endl;
    //calls function to count lowest vaccination rate and country name
    lowest(countries, vaccinations);
    //calls function to print the average vaccination rate
    //average(countries, vaccinations);
}

void welcomeMessage() {
    cout << "Welcome to the vaccine data analysis program!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "This program will print which country currently has admistered the most COVID-19 vaccine doses per 100 people" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The program will also print which country currently has administered the least, per 100 people, as well as the average dose administration per 100 people, out of 127 countries on the list." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void file(string country[], double vaccinations[]) {
    int index = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("vaccinations.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    } else {
        while (index < 127) {
            //add code to isolate country string
            inFile >> country[index];
            //add code to isolate vaccination percentage
            inFile >> vaccinations[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
}

void highest(string country[], double vaccinations[]) {
    string highestCountry = country[0];
    int highestTotal = vaccinations[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 127; i++) {
        if (vaccinations[i] > highestTotal) {
            highestTotal = vaccinations[i];
            highestCountry = country[i];
        }
    }
    cout << highestCountry << " has the highest number of vaccinations at " << fixed << setprecision(100) << highestTotal << " per 100 people." << endl;
}


void lowest(string country[], double vaccinations[]) {
    string lowestCountry = country[0];
    int lowestTotal = vaccinations[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 127; i++) {
        if (vaccinations[i] < lowestTotal) {
            lowestTotal = vaccinations[i];
            lowestCountry = country[i];
        }
    }
    cout << lowestCountry << " has the lowest number of vaccinations at " << fixed << setprecision(100)<< lowestTotal << " per 100 people." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Consider using Modern C++, it'll reduce your problem down to one file read, and one algorithm call.

Comment: Could you remove the noise from your [mre]? There is certainly no need for a welcome message. Also, it seems unlikely that demonstrating the issue requires more than reading *one line* from the file, then printing the name and number from that one line.

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the precision to 100 decimal places? 2 seems sufficient.

Comment: @Casey I think it was added in the effort to get decimals off integer numbers... Per you suggestion, I rewrote it with a single combined file read/algorithm call

Answer (score 4):

You declared

```
int highestTotal = vaccinations[0];
```

therefore, it drops decimals when you copy floating point values into it.

Declaring `highestTotal` and `lowestTotal` as doubles should help:

```
double highestTotal = vaccinations[0];
```

and

```
double lowestTotal = vaccinations[0];
```

EDIT: as @Casey suggests, we can slightly rewrite it (you can add the welcome message and file correctness check if you wish);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Country {
    string name;
    double rate;
};

istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Country& country) {
    return in >> country.name >> country.rate;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("vaccinations.txt");
    auto comparator = [](const Country& x, const Country& y) { return x.rate < y.rate; };
    auto [min, max] = minmax_element(istream_iterator<Country>{inFile}, istream_iterator<Country>{}, comparator);
    string highestCountry = max->name;
    double highestTotal = max->rate;
    cout << highestCountry << " has the highest number of vaccinations at " << highestTotal << " per 100 people." << endl << endl;
    string lowestCountry = min->name;
    double lowestTotal = min->rate;
    cout << lowestCountry << " has the lowest number of vaccinations at " << lowestTotal << " per 100 people." << endl;
}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that `stream_iterator`s are a thing. I would have read the whole file into memory as a `std::string`, copied it into a `std::stringstream`, streamed *that* into a `std::map<std::string, double>` and then called `minmax_element` with a lambda. It's longer in code, but it hits the disk only once, so it's got that going for it.

Comment: @Casey Map gives O(n log n), while with vector<string, double> it's linear complexity. You are correct though that disk is likely to be the main bottleneck

Comment: Yes, `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>>` is probably better considering the number of values in the file are known at 127.